# Does a similar mysql function like coalesce exists for field data which errors out during insert?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

Since some of the datetime values are future dates. My mysql sql insert is failing with the error below.

```
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '2038-01-28 14:13:01' for column 'column_date_time' at row 3
```

Is there a mysql function similar to coalesce but for errors, that way when this error occurs, it grabs the value of now() instead?

Here is the sql code:

```
INSERT INTO rl (id, ad_id, leased_date_time)
SELECT 0, unit_id, max_end_time FROM
(
    SELECT
        0,
        sps.units_id as unit_id,
        max(sps.publish_schedule_endtime) as max_end_time
    FROM publish_schedule as sps
        join units as su on(su.units_id = sps.units_id)
        join properties as sp on(sp.properties_id = su.properties_id)
        join owners as so on(so.owners_id = sp.owners_id)
    WHERE
        DATE(sps.publish_schedule_endtime) > date(date_sub(now(), interval 12 month))
        AND DATE(sps.publish_schedule_begintime) <> DATE(sps.publish_schedule_endtime)
        AND so.owners_email like '%searchstr%'
    group by su.units_id
) leased_ads
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE leased_date_time=(now());
```

And the destination table structure:

```
mysql> desc rl;
+------------------+-------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| Field            | Type              | Null | Key | Default           | Extra             |
+------------------+-------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| id               | smallint unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment    |
| ad_id            | smallint unsigned | NO   | UNI | 0                 |                   |
| leased_date_time | timestamp         | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED |
+------------------+-------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the code that is generating this error?

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff I added more detail to the post.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have got it working by using an IF statement in the SELECT statement. Here is the code that worked:

```
INSERT INTO rl (id, ad_id, leased_date_time)
SELECT 0, unit_id, IF(max_end_time > NOW(), NOW(), max_end_time) FROM
(
    SELECT
        0,
        sps.units_id as unit_id,
        max(sps.publish_schedule_endtime) as max_end_time
    FROM publish_schedule as sps
        join units as su on(su.units_id = sps.units_id)
        join properties as sp on(sp.properties_id = su.properties_id)
        join owners as so on(so.owners_id = sp.owners_id)
    WHERE
        DATE(sps.publish_schedule_endtime) > date(date_sub(now(), interval 12 month))
        AND DATE(sps.publish_schedule_begintime) <> DATE(sps.publish_schedule_endtime)
        AND so.owners_email like '%searchstr%'
    group by su.units_id
) leased_ads
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE leased_date_time=(now());
```